# SQL - How to optimize the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have wrote the following query which extracts all users which are in child departments of current user's department.
Current user cames from client app, but I Decalred it here in SQL for tests reason.

```
DECLARE @UserID INT = 72

SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE Department_Id IN ( 
                        SELECT DISTINCT Id    /*, idp*/
                        FROM departments
                        WHERE idp IN (
                                        SELECT Department_Id 
                                        FROM users 
                                        WHERE Id = @UserID
                                        )
                        )

OR Department_Id IN (
                        SELECT DISTINCT idp
                        FROM departments
                        WHERE idp IN (
                                        SELECT Department_Id 
                                        FROM users 
                                        WHERE Id = @UserID
                                        )
                        )
```

I wanted to select the **Id** and the **idp** from **departments** to have a short query, but when i use this way it returns me an SQL error :

*Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.*

This is because my list should contain only one column, but not 2.

Please advice me any way to reduce this query, especially the second part (after **OR**) which is a copy-paste of first (before **OR**)

Thank you.

Comment: Hiya, you can have multiple distinct in same statement see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns-postgresql - hope this helps, cheers

Comment: So this is not about optimizing query performance, but about "optimizing" the query **syntax**, right?

Comment: @ Branko Dimitrijevic , yes - you're right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts...

1. Nested IN subqueries are unlikely to be friendly.
2. You don't need DISTINCT when using IN

I'd use GROUP BY to deal with the 1:many relationships, but as your answer is using an alternative structure, I'll try to keep close to what you have...

```
DECLARE @UserID INT = 72

SELECT
  *
FROM
  users AS associates
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 
      *
    FROM
      users
    INNER JOIN      
      departments
        ON departments.idp = users.Department_Id
    WHERE
      users.id = @user_id
      AND (   departments.id  = associates.department_id
           OR departments.idp = associates.department_id)
  )
```

If you did use the GROUP BY approach, you avoid sub-queries and correlated-sub-queries all together...

```
DECLARE @UserID INT = 72

SELECT
  associates.id
FROM
  users
INNER JOIN      
  departments
    ON departments.idp = users.Department_Id
INNER JOIN
  users AS associates
    ON associates.department_id = departments.id
    OR associates.department_id = departments.idp
WHERE
  users.id = @user_id
GROUP BY
  associates.id
```

If there any other fields in `associates` that you need, just add them to the SELECT ***and*** the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `EXISTS` like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users u
WHERE  EXISTS(  SELECT *
                FROM   departments
                WHERE  idp IN (SELECT Department_Id FROM users WHERE Id = @UserID)
                       AND (id = u.Department_Id
                           OR idp = u.Department_Id)    )
```

Comment: To reduce the number of lines of code further you could replace `AND (id = u.Department_Id OR idp = u.Department_Id)` in the exists subquery with `u.Department_Id IN (ID, IDP)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE Department_Id IN ( 
                    SELECT myId FROM 
                     ( SELECT Id AS myId
                       FROM departments
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT idp AS myId
                       FROM departments
                     ) A 
                    WHERE A.myId IN (
                                    SELECT Department_Id 
                                    FROM users 
                                    WHERE Id = @UserID
                                    )
                    )
```

Comment: **@Indikaf**, this query returns only one item which is the parent. I found that the answer offered by **wqw** is a good answer